# How to use play framework config library command line parameters in non play application

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt, jvm-arguments, typesafe-stack

In play application I can add command line parameters to override default config in resourses:

`... -Dconfig.file=/opt/conf/prod.conf`

I develop non-play application with play config library and generate jar with sbt-assembly.

**Upd**
I want use command line params:

`java -jar my-app.jar -Dconfig.file=/opt/conf/prod.conf`

but there is no effect.  I load config with:

`ConfigFactory.load()`

Should I manually resolve cmd params and load file into config?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found mistake:

`-Dconfig.file` is a system parameter. System parameters should be written before `-jar`. Other way they are interpreted as command line parameters. So correct solution:

```
java -Dconfig.file=/opt/conf/prod.conf -jar my-app.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Play just use typesafe-config. https://github.com/typesafehub/config

You can use same feature by adding the dependency into your build.sbt, and use Config class.

Comment: Thanks for response. I have problem with cmd params. I upd my question.